# How to add `:dependent => :destroy` declaration on already created Rails ActiveRecord Postgresql DB table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a `post` ActiveRecord model that `has_many` comments, but I forgot to add `:dependent => :destroy` upon declaring it. Now I have several posts with comments and I cannot delete them as I get this error:

```
PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  update or delete on table "posts" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_c9b8ba77e9" on table "comments"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(2) is still referenced from table "comments".
```

I after the fact added the `:dependent => :destroy` declaration, but I am pretty sure I cannot do that, so how do I create a migration that does it?

Comment: Actually this should work. Did you try locally?

Comment: well this is not a production app, it is my first Rails app I am developing now while learning Rails. I tried to create `db/seeds.rb` script that first deletes everything that I had created while developing and then to create new posts. However, it throws this error on `Post.delete_all`

Comment: The problem is because you are calling `.delete_all` and in order for the `dependent: :destroy` to work you should call `.destroy_all`

Comment: `delete_all` doesn't call `:dependent` option

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem like so:

```
class UpdateChartForeignKey < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    remove_foreign_key :comments, :posts
    add_foreign_key :comments, :posts, on_delete: :cascade
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
end
```

This will add the :dependent => :destroy declaration to the User model's association with the posts table, indicating that when a user is deleted, all of the associated posts should also be deleted.

Comment: but does it work if I add it after I've already created the table and created posts/comments. Do I need a migration - that was the question. It didn't work when I added it _after the fact_